# Get all html between two elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, c#-3.0

Problem:
Extract all html between two headers including the headers html. The header text is known, but not the formatting, tag name, etc. They are not within the same parent and might (well, almost for sure) have sub children within it's own children).

To clarify: headers could be inside a `<h1>` or `<div>` or any other tag. They may also be surrounded by `<b>`, `<i>`, `<font>` or more `<div>` tags. The key is: the only text within the element is the header text.

The tools I have available are: C# 3.0 utilizing a WebBrowser control, or Jquery/Js.

I've taken the Jquery route, traversing the DOM, but I've ran into the issue of children and adding them appropriately. Here is the code so far:

```
function getAllBetween(firstEl,lastEl) {
    var collection = new Array(); // Collection of Elements
    var fefound =false;
    $('body').find('*').each(function(){
        var curEl = $(this);
        if($(curEl).text() == firstEl) 
            fefound=true;
        if($(curEl).text() == lastEl) 
            return false;

        // need something to add children children
        // otherwise we get <table></table><tbody></tbody><tr></tr> etc
        if (fefound)
            collection.push(curEl);
    });
    var div = document.createElement("DIV");
    for (var i=0,len=collection.length;i<len;i++){
        $(div).append(collection[i]);
    }
    return($(div).html());
}
```

Should I be continueing down this road? With some sort of recursive function checking/handling children, or would a whole new approach be better suited?

For the sake of testing, here is some sample markup:

```
<body>
<div>
<div>Start</div>
<table><tbody><tr><td>Oops</td></tr></tbody></table>
</div>
<div>
<div>End</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Any suggestions or thoughts are greatly appreciated!

Comment: I am very confused as to what you are trying to do.  You want to extract all HTML of an element that is known, but the contents of the element is not known?  How about innerHTML / html() ..?

Comment: All the HTML between two elements as identified by their `.InnerText`, but I do not know, nor control, what is between them or any other pieces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My thought is a regex, something along the lines of

```
.*<(?<tag>.+)>Start</\1>(?<found_data>.+)<\1>End</\1>.*
```

should get you everything between the Start and end div tags.

Comment: My apologies, I need to clarify my question a bit... with regards to using regex the headers are the -only- text in it's html element. I'm surmising that using regex would fail if "Start" and "End" were in other parts of the document.

Comment: other parts of the document? the regex doesn't care where the pattern is.

Comment: What if there was <div>The following is the <b>Start</b> section.</div>... Wouldn't the regex hook on to that Start?

Comment: Depends on the regex, the one I wrote would not hook to that start but another regex could. The one i wrote requires <something>Start</something> as the start tag, where something could be hardcoded as "div" if need be. Flexibility is one of strong points of regexes, unfortunatly readability isn't.

Comment: Marking this correct as it lead me down the right path. Basically I use my original code to find the start/end tag names and give them a unique ID. Then I adopted this answers regex using those variables.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an idea:

```
$(function() {
      // Get the parent div start is in:
    var $elie = $("div:contains(Start)").eq(0), htmlArr = [];

      // Push HTML of that div to the HTML array
    htmlArr.push($('<div>').append( $elie.clone() ).html());

      // Keep moving along and  adding to array until we hit END
    while($elie.find("div:contains(End)").length != 1) {
        $elie = $elie.next();       
        htmlArr.push($('<div>').append( $elie.clone() ).html());
    };

      // htmlArr now has the HTML
      // let's see what it is:
    alert(htmlArr.join(""));
});​
```

### **[Try it out with this jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/kTVQY/)**

This takes the entire parent `div` that `start` is in. I'm not sure that's what you want though. The outerHTML is done by `$('<div>').append( element.clone() ).html()`, since outerHTML support is not cross browser yet. All the html is stored in an array, you could also just store the elements in the array.